# Why is a elementwise max not DCP?

Tags: constrained-optimization, convex-optimization, cvx, cvxpy

I am trying to formulate a convex optimization problem using CVXPY. Everything works, except a constraint that does not seem to follow DCP rules.

Let $D \in \Bbb R^n$ be a decision variable and let $Q$ be another decision variable that is derived from $D$ using the following constraint,

```
Q = cvxpy.pos(D)
```

I am not sure why this is the case. [Here](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html#elementwise-functions) it states that `pos` is a convex atom.

$$ \mbox{pos} (x) := \max \{ x, 0 \} $$

Can someone please help me?

Edit:

Error message:

> cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
> The following constraints are not DCP: var1 == maximum(var0, 0.0) ,
> because the following subexpressions are not: |--  var1 ==
> maximum(var0, 0.0)

Minimum working example (if the 2nd constraint is switched off the program works),

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

D = cp.Variable(2)
A = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 1]])
b = np.ones((2, )) * 2
Q = cp.Variable(2)

constraints = [sum(D) == 1, Q == cp.pos(D)]

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(A @ D - b)), constraints)

prob.solve(verbose=True)
```

Comment: Post the error message you're getting and a MWE? Importantly, are you minimizing or maximizing your objective?

Comment: Added a MWE and error message, I am minimizing the obj func

Comment: CVXPY is objecting to the nonlinear equality constraint, which is (non-convex) and not DCP-compliant. I'm not sure how Q is used in your problem, but do you actually want the constraint D >= 0? if so, use that. (Note: I am a CVX user, not CVXPY).

Comment: My bad, let me add some context to what I am trying to do with Q. My intent is to add Q as a regularization term in the objective function. 
$Reg Term = M^{T} Q$
But, this regularization needs to be applied only to the negative entries in the vector D, which is why I am trying to do a pos. Here $M$ is a vector containing some regularization multipliers

Comment: Did you mean "regularization needs to be applied only to the NONnegative entries"? Don't use a constraint. Apply the pos or max(D,0) directly in the objective function expression. In CVX, that would be ... + M'*pos(D)   I'll let you figure out the syntax in CVXPY.

Comment: Thank you, this works for M > 0, how do I get this to work for negative cases as well? eg. M = [0.5, -0.5], I am guessing the negative entry changes the curvature from convex to concave. This is part of the reason why I was exploring the constraint route.

Also, why does this work with the obj func and not as a constraint?

Comment: Nonlinear equality constraints are not allowed by DCP, and other than trivial cases, they are non-convex.  masx(D,) <= something is allowed; max(D,0) >= something is not allowed. The term -max(Q,0) is non-convex, so not usable in a minimization objective function in CVXPY. If you really want a non-convex objective, you will need to use a non-convex (modeling system and) solver.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is based on @Mark L. Stones' comments

Nonlinear equality constraints are not allowed by DCP, and other than trivial cases, they are non-convex. Apply the pos or max(D,0) directly in the objective function expression. In CVX, that would be ... + M'*pos(D)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).